# Creating primary key based off of a primary key from another table

Tags: mysql, primary-key, auto-increment

I have a table that looks like this (only showing a few of the columns as an example), where the ID is being auto incremented:

```html
('client' table)

client_id | state | concerns
__________|_______|_________
    01    |   MA  |   ...
    02    |   NJ  |   ...
    03    |   MA  |   ...
```

I have another table, and what I want to do for the PK of that table is to create it based on the PK from the 'client' table. (A client can be one person, or two)

```html
('person' table)

    person_id | fname |     dob    | client_id
    __________|_______|____________|__________
        01A   |   MA  |  1/1/1978  |    01   
        01B   |   MA  |  2/7/1985  |    01
        02    |   NJ  |  5/17/1983 |    02
        03A   |   MA  |  3/12/1970 |    03
        03B   |   MA  |  5/23/1987 |    03
```

So it will only add the letters to the PK if the client consists of two people (notice how 'person_id' stayed as 02).

How should I go about doing this? I'm not sure if having it as '01_1', '01_2' would make it easier than having it look like '01A', '01B', but whichever way makes it easiest would be preferred! Thank you in advance!

**(I forgot to mention that I'm using MySQL, if that makes a difference!)

Comment: don't do that. just put the extra bit into its own field, so you'll have `(01,1), (01,2), (02,1), etc...`

Answer (score 0):

You needs to create a foreign key that references to client id, and then make it a primary key. I suggest you to create others columns for specific data.

Here is a sample, I ignored others columns:

```
CREATE TABLE client (
    client_id CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY(client_id),
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE person (
    client_id CHAR(40),
    person CHAR(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (client_id, person),
    FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client(client_id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```